# how to use one for each loop for two arrays in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

In my web application, I have multiple text boxes with same name. using button click event, it will add textboxes dynamically. User enter email address.

Following javascript shows that using for each loop, it will save all the email addresses which entered by user in database.

```
 function JavaScriptFunction() {   
 var arr = $("[name='multiple[]']");
 $.each(arr, function (i, item) { PageMethods.InsertContacts($(item).val(),"01132321","M0011", getValues_Success, getValues_Fail);
  });
```

This is my web page

```
                        <div class="form-group multiple-form-group input-group">                           
                            <input type="text" name="multiple[]" class="form-control" />                          
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-add">+</button>
                            </span>
                        </div>

                         <div class="form-group multiple-form-group input-group">                           
                            <input type="text" name="multiple[]Phone" class="form-control" />                          
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-add">+</button>
                            </span>
                        </div>

                     <input type="button" onclick="JavaScriptFunction();" value="get Values" />
```

code behind method

```
  [WebMethod]
public static string InsertContacts(string email ,string phone, string username)
{
    userDataHandler.InsertContacts(email, phone, username);
    return "success";
}
```

As the same way, user add phone numbers. I want to read the array and save the data in database. I can read the array in two loops and save the data. But I want to read those two arrays in one loop and save the data in two columns.

I tried like this, but it does not work.

```
var arr = $("[name='multiple[]']");
var arr2 = $("[name='multiple[]Phone']");

$.each(arr,arr2 function (i, item,item2) {
  PageMethods.InsertContacts($(item).val(),$(item2).val(),"M0011", getValues_Success, getValues_Fail);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are of same length then it is possible in a single loop.

```
var arr = $("[name='multiple[]']");
var arr2 = $("[name='multiple[]Phone']");

$.each(arr, function (i, item) {
  PageMethods.InsertContacts(arr[i].val(),arr2[i].val(),"M0011", getValues_Success, getValues_Fail);
});
```

If they are of different lengths then use two loops

```
$.each([arr, arr2], function() {
    $.each(this, function(i, v) {
        // do something
    });
});
```

Comment: I write the same length code which you have given me. But it does not work email and phone data does not save in the database. I write alert message , it also doesn't work. please can you help me why it's not work.

Comment: inside `.each()` just try adding `console.log(arr[i].val()+"  "+arr2[i].val());` and check the console for output. Also please post your `HTML`.

Comment: I add that line. where can i see console.log output?

Comment: Press F12, See console.

Comment: or instead do `alert(arr[i].val()+" "+arr2[i].val());`

Comment: Why are you using `$.each` their is just one one input with both the names

Comment: $.each(arr, function (i, item) {
 alert(arr[i].val()+" "+arr2[i].val());
 });        Is  this wrong? alert massage box does not display.

Comment: I said, Their are just two inputs one with name='multiple[] and other with name='multiple[]Phone.. So why are you using $.each?

Comment: Actually, I new in Javascript.

Comment: Okay tell me what do you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

This my html page

```
<form roe="form" runat="server">
         <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" ScriptMode="Release" />

    <!--Header-->
    <UsersHeaderTP:UsersHeaderTN runat="server" ID="UserHeaderTN1" />

    <!--Page Content-->
    <div class="container1">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="stepwizard">
                    <div class="stepwizard-row setup-panel">
                        <div class="stepwizard-step">
                            <a href="#step-1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">1</a>
                            <p>Step 1</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="stepwizard-step">
                            <a href="#step-2" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">2</a>
                            <p>Step 2</p>
                        </div>
                     <%--   <div class="stepwizard-step">
                            <a href="#step-3" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">3</a>
                            <p>Step 3</p>
                        </div>--%>
                    </div>
                </div>

                    <div class="row setup-content" id="step-1">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <h3>Step 1</h3>


                             <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="contacts">
                                <label>Contacts:</label>

                                <div class="form-group multiple-form-group input-group">                           
                                    <input type="text" name="multiple[]" class="form-control" />                          
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-add">+</button>
                                    </span>
                                </div>

                                 <div class="form-group multiple-form-group input-group">                           
                                    <input type="text" name="multiple[]Phone" class="form-control" />                          
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-add">+</button>
                                    </span>
                                </div>

                             <input type="button" onclick="JavaScriptFunction();" value="get Values" />                              
                            </div>

                        </div>


                        </div>
                    </div>                      
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
           <div id="div1"></div>
    <!-- Content -->
    <div class="container">

        <!-- Footer -->
        <footertp:footertn runat="server" id="HeaderTN1" />
    </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

no there is no one input, using button click event it will add text boxes. textbox name are equal. User enter add email by using button click event.

using the following javascript, I have save all the email address which user entered in each text boxes. In same way, user  add phone numbers.

```
 var arr = $("[name='multiple[]']");
    $.each(arr, function (i, item) {

   PageMethods.InsertContacts($(item).val(),"0111" ,"M0011", getValues_Success, getValues_Fail);
   });
```

The above code works. As you can see I have write "0111". In there I have to insert the values which are added by user. The Following code shows phone numbers which are added by user, all the phone number get saved.

```
var arr2 = $("[name='multiple[]Phone']");
    $.each(arr2, function (i, item) {

    PageMethods.InsertPhone($(item).val(), "M0011", getValues_Success, getValues_Fail);
   });
```

I done this code separately. but I want to pass list of email and phone number into one mehtod. Can you suggest me any method to do that.